# Identifying cookies so that I can log into a Website using Python

Tags: python-3.x, session-cookies

I have the following code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import *
with requests.Session() as c:
   url = "website login page"
   url2 = "website home page"
   USERNAME = 'myTaxID'
   PASSWORD =  'myPassword'
   c.get(url)
   EVENT="the value found in the form data"
   VIEW="the value found in the form data"
   login_data = dict(__VIEWSTATE=VIEW, __EVENTVALIDATION=EVENT, 
   txtTaxID=USERNAME, txtPassword=PASSWORD)
   c.post(url, data= login_data)
   data = c.get(url2)
data2 = BeautifulSoup(data.text,"html.parser")
print(data2.title)
```

The code does not bomb, however, it does not take me to the home page. I am guessing that I am missing some need info. Do I need to satisfy below?
I am trying to determine what parameters I need to satisfy to login.
The form data has the following fields:

- __VIEWSTATE
- __EVENTVALIDATION
- txtTaXID
- txtPassword
- btnLogin.x
- btnLogin.y

The last two fields have varying values.
Do I need t eneter all parameters to login? How do I obtain the value of the varying fields?

Thank you!

Comment: We cannot speculate on how a particular website is operated, without knowing which website it is.

Comment: I *can* speculate that the web server probably was written in [ASP.NET](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=__VIEWSTATE&t=ffab&ia=qa).

Comment: Okay.  What does that imply?

Comment: It implies that I can't figure out much from what I see. However, I'd guess the `x` and `y` refers to the coordinates of the login button on the screen. You could try putting in random values. But, it might exist as a way to deter folks from writing a web scraper. If so, you should think about whether doing so is an ethical or legal pursuit.

Comment: I understand. I only intend to use the code to download monthly information that is uploaded to the site. Being that it is my personal account, I see no harm in trying to do so automatically.

Comment: From what I understand, the fields are equivalent to csfr_malware_token. (-something I have seen a lot of the internet.)

Comment: Okay. If a CSRF token is involved, you'll need to grab the values off of the login page in order to proceed. Good luck!